# Number of factors based on prime factors in a monoid?

Tags: combinatorics, semigroups, monoid

This is different to the other questions asking for the number of factors of a natural number based on the number of prime factors because the group is non-commutative.

If I have a monoid $(M, *)$ with some elements which are "prime" (i.e. $\{n :\neg(\exists a,b \in M, a \neq e, b \neq e: a * b = n) \land n \neq e\}$), 
 where each composite element has a unique prime factorization (i.e. $p_1 * p_2 * p_3\ldots* p_a = n$, where the order of $p_1, p_2,\ldots p_a$ is also included in the definition of uniqueness) then given the prime factorization of an element, how many factors does that element have?

I feel like this should be a fairly simple combinatorics problem, but I just can't figure out the answer.

Comment: There is no guarantee in general that prime factorizations either exist or are unique, and the question of what uniqueness means is complicated if $M$ isn't required to be commutative. There's also the question of what to do with units, e.g. is $2 = (-2)(-1)$ a different factorization from $2 = 2 \cdot 1$ in the multiplicative monoid of nonzero integers?

Comment: Okay, but I do know in this particular monoid (because of what it models) that there is definitely exactly one sequence of $p_1 * p_2 * p_3 \ldots * p_a = n$ for any given n if $p_1$, $p_2$, etc. are all prime and $n$ is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the set of prime elements. Your condition on $M$ implies that $M$ is the free monoid $A^*$. It follows that the number of (nonempty) factors of an element $a_1 \dotsm a_n$ is $n+1 \choose 2$.

Comment: I edited my original answer, which was wrongly using $n$ instead of $n+1$. For instance, $a_1a_2a_3$ has $6 = {4 \choose 2}$ nonempty factors: $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_1a_2, a_2a_3, a_1a_2a_3$